# Inheriting constructors with default arguments: Which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, g++

In C++11, you can inherit all constructors from a base class. How does constructor inheritance behave with respect to default arguments?

Consider the following code:

```
struct Base
{
    Base(int x, int y=0, int z=0)
    {

    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    using Base::Base;
};

int main() {
    Base B(1,2);
    Derived D(2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

This does not compile on MSVC13, with the following error:

```
 ..\constructor_test\main.cpp(16) : error C2660: 'Derived::Derived' : function does not take 2 arguments
```

However, it works fine on GCC (see http://ideone.com/nNmXHo). So my questions are:

Shouldn't constructors for one, two and three arguments be generated? Which compiler is correct here? MSVC13 or GCC?
If GCC is correct, is there any known workaround for MSVC (apart from explicitly specifying the constructors again)?

Comment: please take a look at this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable  where it is clearly stated that visual studio does not support it (yet)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I only searched for the special case of constructor inheritance WITH default arguments and missed the fact that even basic inheritance isn't supported. If you made that an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc compiler is correct.

As you have mentioned, Constructors for one, two and three arguments should be generated.

Comment: This is explained in 12.9/1 and 12.9/6 of the standard.